# Как сделать выборку jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать выборку элемента, чтобы каждый раз, когда выбирался новый элемент `option` в поле "Выбор из фактур", сохранялось это значение в переменной, и потом это можно вывести как числовое значение?

Вот пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/5/

Пример исправлен на правильный прошу прощения :)

Comment: Вы уверены, что это тот пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var texture = 0;
$('#russ').change(function(){
    texture = $(this).val();
});
```